# Как заставить блок при ховере перекрывать другие блоки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Как заставить красный блок  при ховере на половину перекрывать желтый блок(желтый должен остаться на месте)?
    Как заставить желтый блок при ховере перекрывать красный и зеленый блок поровну(красный и зеленый блоки должны остаться на местах)?
    Как заставить зеленый блок на половину уйти вправо и наслоиться на желтый блок?

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/AAChibilyaev/nwu1rsgw/4/)!

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="one">
    <div class="subOne">
        1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="one" style="background: yellow; height: 150px;margin-top:10px; ">
    <div class="subOne">
       2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="one" style="background: green;">
    <div class="subOne">
       3
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицательный margin все решает))

https://jsfiddle.net/nwu1rsgw/5/

```
.first:hover{
    margin-right:-50px;
}

.second:hover{
    margin:0 -20px;
}

.third:hover{
    margin-left:-40px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Максимально понятно)))